# Attribute "ng-click" not allowed on element in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, angularjs

I just love AngularJs. I write all my projects in netbeans and I would like to stick with netbeans. I searched over the net for a plugin that supports AngularJs in netbeans, with no luck.

There is a [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40296/), but it seems not to work, or I can not get it to work.

I am not looking for a full fledged plugin, if I could get rid of the warnings in the editor I would be satisfied.

My questions:

1. Does anyone know a working plugin for netbeans that supports AngularJs?
2. If not, a link to instructions how to make netbeans understand a custom attribute would also help/

Comment: just FYI, directives can be prefixed with `data` so `ng-click` can be expressed as `data-ng-click`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can prefix them with data- or x- ...